# Qt: How to sign up for phone call notification?

Tags: qt, notifications, phone-call

I have looked around to find something that could help me receive notification in my app when the device is receiving a phone call.

I found this: [QTelephonyCallInfo](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtmobility-1.1-tp/qtelephonycallinfo.html)

But the that one doesn't seem to exist any more.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am using QDesktopServices for calling a number:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("tel:*number*"));
```

However, it does not dial automatically. The user must confirm the phone call first.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done in using Qt classes yet.You will have to use native classes to achieve this.
For symbian you might be interested in [CTelephony Class](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Usage_of_CTelephony)